# popover not working in onsen ui with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

i have made a demo on onsenui and i need to use a **popover** in this,I have searched and found a support for popover in onsen ui itself,So i have tried as per steps in below link,[popover in onsen ui](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-popover.html)

**html**

but its not working and says "**TypeError: href is null**" in console,my code is as below,
**html**

```
<ons-page ng-controller="listingController">
    <ons-toolbar style="background: #da1e3e;">

   <div class="left">
     <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
   </div>

        <div class="center">Listing</div>

   <div class="right">
     <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" ng-click="gallery.pushPage('filter.html');" style="border: none; padding: 0 0 4px 0;">
       <i class="ion-android-options" style="font-size:24px; color: #FFFFFF;"></i>
     </span>
<!--      <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height"  ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" >-->
           <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height"  ng-click="show('#navigation')" >-->
         <i class="ion-android-more-vertical" style="font-size:26px;"></i>
       </span>
        <modal visible="showModal"  >
     <ul>
       <h4 align="left">Featured</h4>
  <h4 align="left">Name(A-Z)</h4>
  <h4 align="left">Rating</h4>
 <h4 align="left">Most Popular</h4>
     </ul>
  </modal>
   </div>
 </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="app-page" >
   <div class="list-wrap">
    <ons-list class="list ons-list-inner list--categories" modifier="categories">
        <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div> 

    </ons-list>
   </div>
  </div>



</ons-page>  

<script type="text/ons-template" id="popover.html">
  <ons-popover direction="up down" cancelable>
    <div style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.5;">
      <p>This is a popover!</p>
      <p><small>Click the background to remove the popover.</small></p>
    </div>
  </ons-popover>
</script>
```

**js**

```
ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });
```

pls help me to save..thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge ons-popovers should come under a template. please refer the following code

HTML

```
<div class="navigation-bar__right" ng-controller="myPopoverController">
    <ons-icon class="button button--quiet" icon="ion-ios-information-outline" size="20px" fixed-width="false" ng-click="popover.show($event)"></ons-icon>
</div>
<ons-template id="myPopover.html">
    <ons-popover cancelable direction="down">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <ons-list>
                <ons-list-item>List 1</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item>List 2</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item>List 3</ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
        </div>
    </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

JS

```
myApp.controller('myPopoverController', function ($scope) {

    ons.createPopover('myPopover.html').then(function (popover) {
        $scope.popover = popover;
    });
});
```